# How to Solve Problems to Generate Numerical Values

Tags: r

I'm not able to transform them into numerical values. I did it as follows: `df1<-df1 %>% mutate(across(starts_with("DR1"), as.numeric)`). What am I wrong about?

```
df1<-structure(list(date1 = structure(c(1639612800, 1639612800, 1639612800, 
1639612800, 1639612800, 1639612800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), date2 = structure(c(1636934400, 1636934400, 
1636934400, 1636934400, 1636934400, 1636934400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Week = c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday"), Category = c("ABC", "ABC", "CDE", 
"CDE", "FDG", "FDG"), DR1 = c("198.00", "401.38", "0.00", "0.00", 
 "0.00", "0.00"), DR01 = c("188.36", "293.91", "0.00", "0.00", 
 "0.00", "0.00"), DR02 = c("195.00", "282.38", "0.00", "0.00", 
"0.00", "0.00"), DR03 = c("195.00", "288.38", "0.00", "0.00", 
 "0.00", "0.00")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
 "tbl", "data.frame"))

df1<-df1 %>% mutate(across(starts_with("DR1"), as.numeric))

x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))

x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: The `DR0` columns are not numeric.  You may need to convert those to numeric as well

Comment: Instead of doing this in multiple steps, can do `df1 %>% mutate(across(starts_with("DR"), as.numeric), across(starts_with("DR0"), ~ DR1 - ., .names = "{.col}_PV"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `DR` columns here are `character` class.  The OP converted only the 'DR1' columns to `numeric`.  Thus  we get the error when doing the substraction with `DR0` columns.   The three step process which includes creating another object 'x' and then `cbind` can be done more compactly within `tidyverse` itself -  loop `across` the 'DR' columns and convert to `numeric`, then loop `across` the 'DR0' columns, subtract from 'DR1' and create new columns by modifying the `.names` (`{.col}` - returns the original column name, `_PV` adds a suffix to the column name and thus it returns new columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with("DR"), as.numeric), 
          across(starts_with("DR0"), ~ DR1 - ., .names = "{.col}_PV"))
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 6 × 11
  date1               date2               Week   Category   DR1  DR01  DR02  DR03 DR01_PV DR02_PV DR03_PV
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2021-12-16 00:00:00 2021-11-15 00:00:00 Monday ABC       198   188.  195   195     9.64       3       3
2 2021-12-16 00:00:00 2021-11-15 00:00:00 Monday ABC       401.  294.  282.  288.  107.       119     113
3 2021-12-16 00:00:00 2021-11-15 00:00:00 Monday CDE         0     0     0     0     0          0       0
4 2021-12-16 00:00:00 2021-11-15 00:00:00 Monday CDE         0     0     0     0     0          0       0
5 2021-12-16 00:00:00 2021-11-15 00:00:00 Monday FDG         0     0     0     0     0          0       0
6 2021-12-16 00:00:00 2021-11-15 00:00:00 Monday FDG         0     0     0     0     0          0       0
```